# Let's get critical: Oct 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [French Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://french.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://french.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Note values in music terminology](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7380/note-values-in-music-terminology)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Double negation in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7319/double-negation-in-french)

  **Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [How do you say "from cover to cover"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7389/how-do-you-say-from-cover-to-cover)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [“Jouer à” or “jouer de” for sports games?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7323/jouer-a-or-jouer-de-for-sports-games)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How does the passé composé change in passive voice?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7289/how-does-the-passe-compose-change-in-passive-voice)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Comment traduire "ground term" ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7424/comment-traduire-ground-term)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What is the verb form in “il a dû tomber” ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/what-is-the-verb-form-in-il-a-du-tomber)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- ["Ce à quoi" vs "à quoi"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7493/ce-a-quoi-vs-a-quoi)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [When to use 'je te kiffe'?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7407/when-to-use-je-te-kiffe)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [« Je viens d'Allemagne » ou « je viens de l'Allemagne » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7508/je-viens-dallemagne-ou-je-viens-de-lallemagne)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)